# Hibernate Criteria that compares only 'Minute' component of Date data type

Tags: java, hibernate

I have written a Hibernate criteria to filter and display records that have a certain Time input.

For this, my database has a single record with Date time component 12:30. I have written a Hour('HH') version of this, I feed in (int 12) for hour and it works.

Using a criteria of (int 30) for Minute doesn't return the record in the database. In fact, no matter what I input, it doesn't return. Is there something wrong with the criteria I wrote below?

```
public class MinEqCriteria implements Criterion {

private final String propertyName;
private final int min;

public MinEqCriteria(String propertyName, int min) {
    this.propertyName = propertyName;
    this.min = min;

}

@Override
public String toSqlString(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery)
    throws HibernateException {
        String[] columns = criteriaQuery.findColumns(propertyName, criteria);
        if (columns.length!=1) {
            throw new HibernateException("minEq may only be used with single-column properties");
        }

        String str = "TO_CHAR(" + columns[0] + ",'mm') = ?";

        return str;
    }

@Override
public TypedValue[] getTypedValues(Criteria criteria, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) throws HibernateException {
    return new TypedValue[] {new TypedValue(IntegerType.INSTANCE, min, EntityMode.POJO)};
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "min(" + propertyName + ") = " + min;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Hi Strelok, sorry about that. I mentioned that the code doesn't seem to work and i don't know why. I have edited the question, hopefully it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the answer. Apparently in my sqldeveloper, it is indicated that the format of that data field is "HH:MI". Thus in the Critera code, I should have used the following instead:

String str = "TO_CHAR(" + columns[0] + ",'MI') = ?";